# Funcion predefinida EMPTY() en PHP 5.6

Tags: php, php5

Aca tengo una duda, tengo dos inputs donde meto usuario y contraseña y puse una condición de que si las variables vienen vacias arrojara  un msg para que llenara todos los campos, pero no muestra el msg, coloque un var_dump para ver que traia la variable y en efecto viene vacia

> string(0) "" string(0) ""

pero no entra en la condición IF, alguien sabe por que:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
$username = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['txt1']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password  = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['txt2']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$tsql="";

var_dump($username);
var_dump($password);
if(empty($_POST['txt1']) || empty($_POST['txt2'])){

  $msg='Llena todos los campos!';

}
else{
    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM CatUsuarios WHERE U_UsdName='$username' AND U_Password='$password'";
}



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
while($Row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    if($stmt == true){
        $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }else{

        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
}
```

El HTML comienza aqui. o si tienen alguna mejor idea con un ejemplo para que muestre el mensaje o alert en el mismo panel de logueo

```
  <body>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

                    <div class="brand_logo_container">
                        <img src="midas.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Logo">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">




                    <form action="log.php" form method="POST" >

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="txt1" name="txt1" class="form-control input_user"  placeholder="Usuario">
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="txt2"type="password" name="txt2" class="form-control input_pass"  placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <br>


                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Entrar">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Lo unico que quiero es que valide si los datos ingresados son incorrectos y vacios y lo mantenga en el login sin darle acceso al index, aun estoy en labor de investigacion del mejor metodo, Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow noob69, agregando tu código HTML podemos ayudarte a encontrar de forma más rápida el problema. Te pido lo agreges por favor.

Comment: @PakLeiChong Listo

Comment: Intentaste hacer un var_dump($_POST['txt1']); justo al inicio de tu función ? Qué te regresa?

Comment: string(0) "" string(0) ""

Comment: Quieres validar las credenciales antes o después de sanitizarlas? Porque si quisieras validarlas después, entonces tendrías que modificar tu condición del IF, sustituir $_POST por $username y $password... debería de entrar al IF si la cadena está vacía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que imprima el mensaje debes de agregar la funcion echo al mensaje que esta dentro del if

```
if(empty($_POST['txt1']) || empty($_POST['txt2'])){
  echo $msg='Llena todos los campos!';
}
```